# How to create an Ada DKM project in Workbench for VxWorks with the command line?

Tags: ada, vxworks

I am trying to create a set of projects (VSB +VIP + DKM) for the VxWorks Workbench environment via the command line.

The problem I'm having is that I need the DKM to be an Ada project and I can't find a way to create it with the command console. This is the way it would be created with the graphical interface:
[image]

These are the only options that come up in the console concerning the creation of a DKM:

```
prj dkm create [-force] {-vsb <vsbDir>|-vip <vipDir>|-app <dkmDir>} <project> [-name <name>] [-staticLib]
```

I don't see any option to convert or import an external project.

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In many tools, the GUI way generates a command line and logs it somewhere. If that's so, use the GUI, examine the log, and use that as the starting point for your command line.

Comment: Have you tried using the GNATbench tool? https://www.adacore.com/press/gnatbench-241

Comment: @user_1818839 I have tried to get the log when creating a DKM and then converting it into an Ada project but the log as far as I have seen does not reflect the commands that the tool uses underneath

Comment: @JimRogers I have it integrated with Workbench but I need it to be accessible from the command line